# Shifting gives a 1 at the most significant digit

Tags: c, byte-shifting

Im currently writing a C function that takes a number from the user and converts it into a binary output.  First, here's the code:

```
void Convert_Number_To_Binary(const int num,char *binary) {
    double remainder = num;

    //Start from binary[0] and check if num is divisible by 2^ith power by shifting
    for(int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        int shift = num >> i; //shift the current bit value of remainder i bits
        printf("i: %d, %d \n", i,  (shift) );

        //If shift is greater than 0, then remainder is divisible by 2^i
        if( (shift & 1) > 0) {
                binary[32-i] = '1';
        }
        else
                binary[32-i] = '0';
        //printf("i:%d, 32-i:%d\n", i, (32-i));
    }

    //printf("%c, %c", binary[0], binary[31]);

    binary[33] = '\0';
}
```

The code works fine for the most part, except when I enter an odd number (ex: 17), I get a one in the most siginifanct position:

```
num = 17    binary = 100000000000000000000000000010001
```

The leading "1" doesn't appear for a even number:

```
num = 16    binary = 000000000000000000000000000010000
```

I am running this on a remote 32-bit linux machine, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a binary string of 33 digits, not 32:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    int shift = num >> i; //shift the current bit value of remainder i bits
```

Assuming an `int` is 32 bits wide, on the last iteration of the loop you shift by an amount that is the same size as the variable you're shifting.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This is documented in section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the bitwise shift operators:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  The
> type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.   If
> the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or  is greater than
> or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
> undefined.

Change the stopping point of the loop to 32, and adjust the subtractions and setting of the null terminating byte accordingly.

```
void Convert_Number_To_Binary(const int num,char *binary) {
    //Start from binary[0] and check if num is divisible by 2^ith power by shifting
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        int shift = num >> i; //shift the current bit value of remainder i bits
        printf("i: %d, %d \n", i,  (shift) );

        //If shift is greater than 0, then remainder is divisible by 2^i
        if( (shift & 1) > 0) {
                binary[32-i-1] = '1';
        }
        else
                binary[32-i-1] = '0';
        //printf("i:%d, 32-i-1:%d\n", i, (32-i-1));
    }

    //printf("%c, %c", binary[0], binary[31]);

    binary[32] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first cast the `int` to `unsigned int`, that will force a 0 fill for the MSB.

Something like this:

```
unsigned int shift = (unsigned int)num >> i;
```